# How to calculate the percentage similarity of two users?

Tags: php, percentage

I have some details about two users that are common in both. I want to know how can I get the percentage similarity of both users:
UserA and UserB have:
`

5 mutual friends

8 common products purchased

3 same samples received

9 common followers

etc 
This makes up to a sum of 25 common attributes.`

How can I get the % similarity of both users, Any formula or method ?

Comment: By total number of things, you mean the total things of both users, i.e the sum of all the attributes of both users ?

Comment: just for the sake of sharing. check this link http://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-difference.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `(number of products in common / number of products purchased) * 100`? That's typically how you figure out a percentage. Add up the number of common things and divide it by the total number of things.

If user A has bought 10 things, and user B has bought 20 things, and 5 of A's are the same as 5 of B's, you'd have:

```
((5 + 5) / (10 + 20)) * 100 = 33.3% similar
```

Comment: Why are you adding `5+5` in numerator ?Both users can only have 1 constant number of common things, like 5 common or 10 common etc. I mean if user A and user B have 5 things in common, shouldn't it be `(5/(10+15))*100` ?

Comment: Because it's the total number of common things, which is 10. This produces a much more reasonable number. Would you consider the above two users to be 33.3% (5+5/30) similar, or 16.6% (5/30) similar? *Half* of A's purchases are common, and 25% of B's purchases are common. This doesn't (to me) add up to only 16% commonality.